# validation part not working in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

this is action url

```
  http://localhost/carsdirectory/users/create_ad
```

create_ad.ctp (in this file i have select field , in this field i m fetching data from state_name field table name states )

```
 <label class="ls-details-label">State</label>
 <div class="ls-details-box">
 <?php
 foreach ($states as $state)
 {
    $state_new[$state['State']['id']]=$state['State']['state_name'];
 }
    echo $this->Form->input('Location.state_id',array('label'=>false,'options'=>$state_new,'empty'=>' Select ','class'=>'styledselect_form_1'));
 ?>
 </div>
```

state.php(model)

```
<?php
 class State extends AppModel
     {
var $name = 'State';


            var $validate = array(
            'state_name' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Please select a state')

            );                   
    }
   ?>
```

users_controller.php (controller)

```
 public function create_ad()
 {

 $this->loadModel('Location');
 if($this->Location->saveAll($this->data['Location']))
 {
   $this->data['Car']['location_id'] = $this->Location->id;
 }
 else
  {
$this->Session->setFlash('Detail could not be saved in Cars Controller');
  }
}
```

but validation is not working this msg is not displaying Please select a state and null is insert if i m not select value

i m not able to sort out that problem , so plz help me

thanks in advance, vikas tyagi

Comment: You have to write validate code in `user` model !!

Comment: Rikesh Shah ,should i validate code in user model

Comment: Yes write the code in user model using `state_id` i.e. field name of state in your user table.

Comment: no state_id filed belongs from state table

Comment: its should !! I mean than how you are relating your user table to state ?

Comment: could you explain more how to create relation(that validation can work)

Comment: Check this -> http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1040/Relationship-Types

Comment: There shouldn't need to be an association between the two - he's passing data, and using SaveAll - that should save regardless of relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to validate a `State.state_name` field, but your form's input is `Location.state_id`.  Make sure they match, and try again.